# User Agnet (Browser / Chrome) Progmatically

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, user-agent

I'm new developer on android platform,
Right now i have Sony Xperia ST26, 
I noticed on diffrence user agent between Browser (com.android.browser)
and Chrome (com.android.chrome).

```
Chrome:  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; **ST26i Build**/11.0.A.7.5) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19

Browser:  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; iw-il; **SonyST26i Build**/11.0.A.7.5) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
```

I need a way to get these user agents,

I try with WebView Like this:

```
userAgent = new WebView(this).getSettings().getUserAgentString();
```

and the string is "default" user agnet and not of the embedded browsers.

I try also someting like that, right now the browser (app) display the right user agnet but i need insert this HTML website to String.

```
String url = "http://whatsmyuseragent.com/";
String packageName = "com.android.browser";  
//String packageName ="com.android.chrome";
Intent internetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url)); 
internetIntent.setPackage(packageName);
startActivity(internetIntent);
```

Somebody have idea?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to get the user agent of the embedded webview.  If you have Chrome installed, the embedded WebView still remains the same webview that is distributed with the OS.  There is no Chromium based WebView.

You can also use `System.getProperty("http.agent")` as outlined in http://cdrussell.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/programmatically-get-user-agent-string.html